# Converting back and forth between a position (slot) and coordinate

Tags: java, math

Basically, imagine a position based area with a width of 9 (starting with 0)

```
╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗
║  0 ║  1 ║  2 ║  3 ║  4 ║  5 ║  6 ║  7 ║  8 ║
║  9 ║ 10 ║ 11 ║ 12 ║ 13 ║ 14 ║ 15 ║ 16 ║ 17 ║
║ 18 ║ 19 ║ 20 ║ 21 ║ 22 ║ 23 ║ 24 ║ 25 ║ 26 ║
╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝
```

However, i am not converting to coordinates and back with position 0 as (0,0) This is essentially what i am trying to get

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╗
║ -4,1 ║ -3,1 ║ -2,1 ║ -1,1 ║ 0,1 ║ 1,1 ║ 2,1 ║ 3,1 ║ 4,1 ║
║ -4,2 ║ -3,2 ║ -2,2 ║ -1,2 ║ 0,2 ║ 1,2 ║ 2,2 ║ 3,2 ║ 4,2 ║
║ -4,3 ║ -3,3 ║ -2,3 ║ -1,3 ║ 0,3 ║ 1,3 ║ 2,3 ║ 3,3 ║ 4,3 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

Essentially, the center of the X value is 0, going left or right, decreasing or increasing. However, i have not set the y as a center, since the Y value can expand to infinity.

I need to figure out how to do this with the following methods in Java

```
getPosition(int x, int y);    //RETURNS (int position)
getCoordinates(int position)    //RETURNS (int x, int y)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for modulus and division? http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty sure that is the way to do it, but i'm having issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following methods. Note that i used `java.awt.Point` to represent `x` and `y` coordinates in `getCoordinates(int position)` method.

```
public int getPosition(int x, int y) {
    return ((y - 1) * 9) + (x + 4);
}

public Point getCoordinates(int position) {
    //calculate x and y
    int y = (int) ((position / 9) + 1);
    int x = (position - ((y - 1) * 9)) - 4;

    Point point = new Point(x, y);
    return point;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like what i need, Ill test it out!

Comment: Yes, just wanted to test it. Works!

Comment: I would strongly suggest removing all magic numbers, and replace by final's instead. Then it's a lot easier to change width

Comment: Although it would indeed be more compatible with something bigger as a width, I am using it only once, the width will not change, therefore I don't think I need to change it. It works very well and I want it to be that way. Channa Jayamuni answered exactly what I needed, as I stated in my question that the width is 9